# DTD download/caching

Tags: validation, xhtml, dtd, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have the following directive on top of my master page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

As per the following [article](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic) from W3C they are starting to block DTD download based on a per User Agent string pattern.

Which is the best way to cache the DTD locally or, better more, download it once and then reference a local copy?

I am using IIS 7.5.

Comment: Starting? That article is nearly 3 years old :)

Comment: When does IIS parse XHTML documents? Isn't it just a web server that serves up the files after sticking a Content-Type in the HTTP response header?

Comment: Well, that's an implicit part of the question. Maybe I dont have a problem...

Comment: That is by far the best sort of problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a proxy server like squid to serve it locally -- depending on what "locally" means for you.

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5 as the web server

Comment: That's fine, but I don't think IIS will be parsing the DTD for you.

Answer (score 1):

Install it in your local catalog of DTDs. How you do that depends on the software you are using. [OpenSP, for example, uses the `SGML_CATALOG_FILES` environment variable](http://www.mhoenicka.de/software/sgml/tutorial/cygx1015.html).

You do not need to worry about this unless you are running some sort of XML parser over your documents. If you are just serving them up from a web server, then you won't be touching DTDs.

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5 as the web server